# HTTPS request using Android Volley

Tags: android, ssl, https, android-volley

I am trying to make an HTTPS request via POST with volley but it is not working. The request takes me to onErrorResponse but does not show what the error is. I tested with Postman and it works fine.
I leave part of my code.

```
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

    params.put(PARAM_HASH_TOKEN, HASH_TOKEN);
    params.put(PARAM_USUARIO, id);
    params.put(PARAM_PASSWORD, password);

    JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject(params);
    Log.e("POST",jsonBody.toString());

    JsonObjectRequest mJsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_API, jsonBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            if (response != null) {
                F_PARSEAR_JSON_RESPUESTA(response);
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            String msg = (error.getMessage() == null) ? "Ha ocurrido un error, intentelo de nuevo." : error.getMessage();
            Log.e("ERROR",URL_API);
            Log.e("ERROR",msg);               
            _loginButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
    ApplicationLoader.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(mJsonObjectRequest);
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't show the error? Did you run in debugger and verify that it is null?

Comment: @sam_c that's right, I'm working with the debugger and it does not show the error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check Content type in client and server? They are similar value.

```
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType()
        {
            return "application/json";
        }
```

I hope it will help you!

Comment: does not work =(, think the ssl certificate is not trusted.

Comment: I have experienced similar errors like this, you try to test other Content type .